# Is it true $d(xy)=xdy+ydx$

Tags: calculus

I was going through solution of partial differential equation in my textbook and in one problem $xdy+ydx$ was replaced by $d(xy)$ and solution was carried out. But I cannot understand the part, if these are equal i.e

$d(xy)=xdy+ydx$

and if i integrate at both sides
$\int d(xy)=\int xdy+\int ydx$

I will get

$xy=2xy$

Hence there is extra 2 at right hand side, then how this could be right ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's product rule of derivation

Comment: It is essentially based on carrying out the product rule on $xy$ where both $x$ and $y$ are functions..

Comment: Integrate with respect to what?

Comment: @ElliotG I have edited my question

Comment: If you’re integrating from say the origin to $(a,b)$ on a straight path, you’d get the LHS of $ab$. For the RHS, the average value of $x$ is $a/2$, so the integral of $xdy$ is $ab/2$. Similarly for the other piece.

Comment: $\int x \,dy \ne xy.$

Comment: A visual aid: imagine a rectangle from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$. Suppose the top right corner, at $(x,y)$, moves a bit. The change in area, $d(x,y)$, is essentially going to correspond to a vertical strip on the right ($xdy$) along with a horizontal strip on top ($ydx$).

Answer (score 3):

When you try to write $\int xdy$ and $\int ydx$ as $xy$, you assume for the first integral that $x$ is constant while $y$ varies, and for the second integral $y$ is constant while $x$ varies. This clearly isn't a consistent set of assumptions, especially if you view $x,\,y$ as functions of $t$ (say).

Comment: I was about to leave an answer along these lines. Writing $\int x\,dy$ and $\int y\,dx$ (without limits or mention of path) implies that $x$ is independent of $y$ in the first and $y$ is independent of $x$ in the second. However $\int d(xy) = \int x\,dy + y\,dx = \int (y,x)\cdot(dx,dy)$ makes it clearer that they vary together since you have both as differentials under one integral.

Answer (score 2):

Your integration of the right side is sketchy. You need to apply integration by parts (which is a consequence of the rule), e.g. :

$$\int xdy=xy-\int ydx,$$

and this will cancel with $\int ydx$.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this is just the product rule. To see why it works, there are plenty of proofs out there, but I'll adapt one from Paul's Online Math Notes (https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/DerivativeProofs.aspx).

So we have

$d(xy) = xdy + ydx$

with a little creative rearranging of terms, we get

$d(xy) = (xy)(\frac{dy}{y} + \frac{dx}{x})$

divide both sides by $xy$ to get

$\frac{d(xy)}{xy} = \frac{dy}{y} + \frac{dx}{x}$

Now, we integrate both sides

$\int \frac{d(xy)}{xy} = \int \frac{dy}{y} + \frac{dx}{x}$

$\ln(xy) = \ln(y) + \ln(x)$

Using log rules, we can combine the terms on the right side

$\ln(xy) = \ln(xy)$

Then, exponentiate both sides to get the result

$e^{\ln(xy)} = e^{\ln(xy)}$

$xy = xy$

Comment: "Product rule", not "power rule", no?

Comment: yes, thank you! fingers had a mind of their own there.